# calculate how to get GETDATE() -4 using customer function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

I have a function in my database that is able to spit out a business date like so...

Let's say today is 3/23/2020 - if I run the function like this:

```
select [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1,GETDATE()) ,'PREVIOUS')
```

it will show '03/20/2020' (previous business day. It knows to skip the weekend)

if I do something like

```
select [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, +1,GETDATE()) ,'NEXT')
```

it will show '03/24/2020' (next business day)

Pretty straight forward. This is the only functionality it has. I don't know if it's necessary to share the code as this has some custom filtering not pertaining to what I am doing. For my purpose it can only go back to a previous business day, and to next business day.

My goal is to create a filter in a proc that lets me go back 4 days back like so....

```
Select * from tbl1 where DateField >=DATEADD(dd,-4,GETDATE()) and DateField < GETDATE()
```

the issue with the function is that, it only goes a day backward, so while this seems to work in this scenario, because our last business date is FRIDAY - 4 days

```
DECLARE @daysago AS DATETIME

SELECT @daysago= [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1,GETDATE()),'PREVIOUS') 

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-4,@daysago)
```

However in a case of a scanario where GETDATE() happens to be a Wednesday, and I run the function which will return Tuesday, and if we do `DATEADD(DAY,-4,TUESDAY)` it will return SUNDAY. THe goal here would be to use this function to exclude the weekend and actually go back to previous week's THursday.

EDIT: I'm not even sure if this can be done inside a stored proc utilizing this function. I think it might be actually necessary to create a seperate proc or function to do this type of thing where we check DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATE) to determine if it's a weekend and then utilize the function I have to go back to prev business day (excluding weekend) while keeping a count how many days back we have done already.

Comment: Stop wasting your time. [Implement a real calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) where you can mark every date as needed - whether business, non-work, vacation, holiday, closed-due-to-virus, volcano, etc.

Comment: The alternative is that you change your function (or write a new one) to accept a "day" parameter that determines the direction (before, after) along with the number of business days to decrement / increment.

Comment: Have you tried nesting multiple calls to your function together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able nest a number of your function calls together to go back the number of business days you want.

```
select 
[dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, 
    [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, 
        [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, 
            [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 'PREVIOUS'), 
        'PREVIOUS'), 
    'PREVIOUS'), 
'PREVIOUS')
```

You could also use a common table expression (CTE) to recursively call your function the desired number of times and then select just the one value like this.

```
DECLARE @XDaysAgo DATE;
DECLARE @NumberBusinessDays INT;
SET @NumberBusinessDays = -1;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS DaysBack, [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE(), 'PREVIOUS')) AS MyDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          cte.DaysBack - 1
        , [dbo].[ufGetBusinessDay] (DATEADD(day, -1, cte.MyDate, 'PREVIOUS'))
    FROM  cte
    WHERE cte.DaysBack > @NumberBusinessDays
)
SELECT @XDaysAgo = cte.MyDate 
FROM cte WHERE cte.DaysBack = @NumberBusinessDays;
```